# SyntaxError: C:/workspace/src/app.jsx: Unexpected token (115:36)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

I am new to react.
I am getting a syntax error, can you  tell me why I am getting it?
Providing the code below.

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/workspace/src/app.jsx: Unexpected token (115:36)
  113 |                                 <h6>Your rollover to a  IRA is in progress...</h6>
  114 |                                 {
> 115 |                                     if(this.props.sportsInfo.fundingDetailId === null || this.props.sportsInfo.fundingDetailId === undefined || this.props.sportsInfo.fundingDetailId === '') 
      |                                     ^
  116 |                                     {
  117 |                                         App.rollOverNoContent();
  118 |                                     }
```

Comment: Is the jsx expression closed? (There should be a bracket on a line just after line 118 to close off the jsx expression under the <h6> tag)

Comment: You might want to read the following with regards to inline conditional rendering: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical-ampamp-operator. In your case, that would be `{(this.props.sportsInfo.functionDetailId === null || ...) && App.rollOverNoContent()}`

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#javascript-expressions):

> if statements and for loops are not expressions in JavaScript, so they can't be used in JSX directly. Instead, you can put these in the surrounding code.

Your JSX has to be an expression (roughly speaking, it must return something). You can read more in this [article](http://2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html) from @rauschma.